# Change SharePoint list field color using jQuery code base on value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, sharepoint

I am working with SharePoint list and I need to change the Number field color if it is greater than 60.

I tried to change the code below but it didn't work

This is my code which didn't work (I tried to use gt)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$Text = $("td .ms-vb2:gt('60')").filter(function() {
return $(this).text() == "td .ms-vb2";})
$Text.css("background-color", "#00FF66");
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the SharePoint Stack Exchange (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: sure! It was  too urgent and I posted in both!

Answer (score 0):

See if these two examples help you:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  // option 1

  function tdColor(){
    $( "td:gt(8)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "#00FF66" );
  }
  tdColor();


  //option 2
  function tdColor2(){

    $('td').each(
      function(){
        $("td .ms-vb2:gt(8)").css( "backgroundColor", "#00FF66" );
    });

  }
  tdColor2();

});
```

Full code here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grRBmx

It's best to use var when declaring variables.

Also bare in mind that if the list is dynamically generated jQuery is not working. In this case it's worth having a look at live() function as well.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but I tried both of them and it didn't work. I have added to script editor.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code from the element that contains your list?

Comment: I have posted above. I am not sure if I added in write way but these are HTML in code view of my list.